# Length space and continuity assumption on curves

Tags: metric-spaces, arc-length, metric-geometry

I think the definition of length metric works without assuming curves are continuous.

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x, y\in X$.

**Def 1**. For a function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow X$, $L(f)$ is defined by the sup of the length of polygonal lines associated with a partition of $[0, 1]$. We call $f$ is rectifiable if $L(f)<\infty$.

**Assumption**: For all $x, y\in X$, there is a rectifiable function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x, f(1)=y$.

**Def 2**. For $x, y\in X$, the distance $d(x, y)$ is defined to be the inf of $L(f)$ for rectifieable  functions $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x, f(1)=y$.

I think this $d$ satisfies the axiom of metric without assuming continuity of $f$.

Is it right?

—

**Prop** $d(x, y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$

Proof. (1) $\Leftarrow$ is obvious. (2) If $d(x, y)=0$, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x, f(1)=y, L(f)<\varepsilon$. There is a partition $t_1=0\leq t_1\leq\dots\leq t_n=1$ such that the length $L$ of the polygonal line connecting $f(t_1), \dots, f(t_n)$ is less than $\varepsilon$. So the length of the segment connecting $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Thus $x=y$.

Comment: Which axioms did you try to check? Start with $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$.

Comment: Now, definition 2....

Comment: The continuity of $f$ is to guarantee that $f$ is a curve. Recall that the definition of a _curve_ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can drop the assumption about $f$ being continuous and you will still get a metric. However this won't give you anything interesting. That's because in such scenario, the newely defined metric is just the Euclidean one.

First of all given $f:[0,1]\to X$ (continuous or not), with $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$ we have that $L(f)\geq \lVert x-y\rVert$. That's because of the nature of the Euclidean space: the shortest polygonal chain (or any path) between any two points is just a straight line. Now all you need to realize is that the $L(f)=\lVert x-y\rVert$ equality is always doable if $f$ is not assumed to be continuous. By $f([0,1))=x$ and $f(1)=y$. And therefore $d(x,y)=\lVert x-y\rVert$ has to hold.